# how can i save spring boot log in k8s persistent volume

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, persistent-volumes

I run spring boot in the local environment, the log file is created well.
But when I run it on k8s, it works normally, but I can't find the log.
I tried to go into the pod and search for it, but I couldn't find it.
please help me.
Let me explain the environment I tested.

nfs directory is
"/ktnfs"

logback.xml setting is as below.

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="/ktnfs/kt/logs"/>
<property name="LOG_FILE_NAME" value="api-out"/>
<property name="ERR_LOG_FILE_NAME" value="api-err"/>
```

Below is the yaml file I created.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: kt-nfs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 6Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 172.30.1.80
    path: "/ktnfs"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kt-nfs-pvc
  namespace: kt2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  volumeName: kt-nfs-pv
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kt-api-server
  namespace: kt2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kt-api-server
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kt-api-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: 172.30.1.85:31113/nlu_public/kt-api-server:1.0
        name: kt-api-server
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /ktnfs/kt/logs
            name: kt-nfs-volume
      volumes:
      - name: kt-nfs-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: kt-nfs-pvc
status: {}
```

Comment: What do you get when you try this command in cmd "kubectl logs -f <podname> -n <namespace>" ? (I assume u know how to connect to K8s from command prompt)

Comment: Hello. Could you add logs to the question (kubectl logs <podname> -n kt2)? Did you change the permissions `chmod -R 777 /your/nfs/path` on nfs host?

Comment: @NandhaFrost 
[root@km1 ktnfs]# k logs pod/kt-api-server-57684ffbf9-jdnj5 -n kt2
_______________________   ________
___    |__  __ \___  _/   __  ___/______________   ______________
__  /| |_  /_/ /__  /     _____ \_  _ \_  ___/_ | / /  _ \_  ___/
_  ___ |  ____/__/ /      ____/ //  __/  /   __ |/ //  __/  /
/_/  |_/_/     /___/      /____/ \___//_/    _____/ \___//_/

:: AI Platform API Server :: 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT

2022-03-29 09:22:22.631  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.kt.api.Starter                       []: []

Comment: @mozello my nfs directory already 777

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.
It was a problem that occurred because the logback.xml modifications were not applied when the docker build was done without modifying the version.